# Data Structure for troubleshooting flow?

Tags: data-structures, graph

What data structure would be best for a non-tree (in the graph theory sense), path-saved, troubleshooting flow for a web troubleshooting site?

In plainer words, if I'm wanting to model a troubleshooting flow, such that it's not strictly in a "downward" direction towards a resolution or contact point, is there a more specific structure than just a graph? I'm not worried about efficiency, instead I'm worried about easy of description; the goal is for this to be defined in YAML or some other markup that non-programmers can implement and maintain.

Answer (score 0):

a graph: each node represents a specific state of knowledge (what is known: for example the result of a test to partially identify the problem) then you have directed edges for adding knowledge to arrive at a different node. Optionally use undirected edges to "unknow" or forget a previous assumption on the problem at hand.